# How do I restore multiple objects from S3 Glacier Deep Archive to S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-glacier

First of all, I apologize for my poor English.

I'm having difficulty restoring 'multiple' objects from S3 Glacier Deep Archive to S3.

What I acutally want to do is moving only specific folders and files to FSx, not all data in s3 bucket.

I'm searching the AWS documentation, but I only see guides related to moving single object things.

I think it should be done with CLI command instead of doing it on aws console environment.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: [Restore Amazon S3 objects in S3 Glacier or Glacier Deep Archive](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-batch-operation-initiate-restore/)